# Sending more than one parameter in url in symfony

Tags: symfony, redirect, parameters, getter-setter

i want to send some parameters in array when redirecting and i want the url to keep only the first value in the array. i tried using cookies but i can't send array so i tried to json_encode & json_decode but the results in the other side once page redirected contains only [][][][], i can't get all the values of the array. i tried to use getter and setter but when redirected the value becomes null. in JavaScript i can use localstorage and set my array there and when finished i can clear but in symfony it doesn't exist, how can i do this please help i'm new to symfony development or tell me how to pass an object from one controller to another after redirect page.

```
$this->forward('App\Controller\ActiviteController::new', $toto);
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('activite_new', $toto[0], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER));
```

as shown in the code i did try to forward and after redirect, when forwarding i get the array where i tried to store inside a setter but when it enters the second time for the redirect the getter is cleared and the value is null.

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to do -- you said send some parameters in an array but only want the first value in that array. Why don't you simply pass the first value them instead of attempting to send an array in the first place? 

Are you trying to send those parameters in the URL, as a post or get method?